Can I have 2 worlds with different HDRs backgrounds and switch between them?
I want to have 2 backgrounds on my scene, day and night. I can add 2 worlds with different HDRs as background and easily switch between them.

The problem is when I save and close the project, the next time I open it only saves 1 world and the other disappears.

I have to create the second world and link the hdr everytime I reopen the project.
Can I fix that and always have both worlds?

If you click the shield against the name in the list to create Fake Users on both 'Day' and 'Night' textures and then save the scene you should find that they're both available when you reopen the Blend file. If that works let me know and I'll add it as an answer.

Yes it worked! Thank you.

You should really investigate setting up HDRIs as Assets in future. You can then select the Asset shelf and drag one straight into your scene.
However in this simple case, select each World in turn and click the shield icon to the right of the Scene world name as shown below. Currently the dropdown entry for "Day" has a 0 against it which means that it's not being used and will not be saved with the Blend file. Clicking the  shield icon to hilight it gives the HDRI a 'fake' user ensuring that it will be saved even though nothing is currently using it. (This applies to normal Materials too.)

